# How to retrieve 2 column from 2 tables, column 1 and 2 are count from two tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, join, query

How to retrieve 2 column from 2 tables, column 1 and 2 is (count) from two different tables
and where condition from another table (table 3 )
my query is :

```sql
SELECT ( SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM `tabStudent Group`
         ) AS count_course,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM `tabStudent Group Student` 
         ) AS count_employee
FROM `tabStudent Group` tsg 
JOIN `tabStudent Group Student` tsgs ON (tsg.name = tsgs.parent)
left outer join `tabCourse Schedule` tcs on (tsg.name = tcs.student_group)
where DATE_FORMAT(schedule_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2022-12-01' and '2022-12-28'
group by count_course, 
         count_employee
```

Comment: Please add scripts for ddl and data.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: What table schedule_date in?

Comment: Please use this link: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables and create a table with data. Or share a CSV file